# GeoJSON formats for Leaflet -- certain GeoJSON not displaying, while others are

Tags: javascript, leaflet, gis

I am modifying an example Leaflet script for my custom purposes.

The original had an associated GeoJSON file with the following format (this is just an excerpt):

```
{"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[{"type":"Feature","properties":{"OBJECTID":1,"NAME":"Alpha Terrace","TYPE":"CHD"},"geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[-79.9222757299766,40.4687885729535],[-79.922601544034,40.4688999202888],[-79.9227665690647,40.4689585131248],[-79.9231802736014,40.4691056186529],[-79.9228362255,40.4696697431611],[-79.9224234733987,40.4695244210813],[-79.9222570954656,40.4694656801973],[-79.9222259241735,40.4695164633706],[-79.9219035919843,40.4694017028541],[-79.9222757299766,40.4687885729535]]]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"OBJECTID":2,"NAME":"Manchester","TYPE":"CHD"},"geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[-80.0271753891687,40.4506598454243],[-80.0271940086199,40.4507189442263],[-80.0272105946986,40.4507710471721],[-80.0272579314302,40.4509221686618],[-80.0273032612578,40.4510537660432],[-80.0273193174278,40.451103476753],[-80.0273338296879,40.451147381945],[-80.0273478698275,40.451190610864],[-80.0273633786279,40.4512374152857],[-80.0273793914473,40.4512858394759],[-80.0273919427229,40.4513248923929],[-80.0274084625005,40.4513750227769],[-80.0274174596111,40.451401961247],
```

I made my own GeoJSON with this format (again, just an excerpt):

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"name": "testmap1",
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "land_val": 16290.0, "imprv_val": 0.0, "land_acres": 0.31, "land_sqft": 13503.6, "situs_stre": null, "situs_st_1": "LAKE BREEZE", "situs_st_2": "DR", "situs_city": "BROWNWOOD", "Deed_Date": "2014\/10\/14", "Mkt_Land_S": "FBINT" }, "geometry": { "type": "MultiPolygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ [ 2695178.255351334810257, 10617843.194646343588829 ], [ 2695245.314272344112396, 10618016.961359173059464 ], [ 2695316.911570087075233, 10617988.845273673534393 ], [ 2695251.204024344682693, 10617828.19828525185585 ], [ 2695196.89442166686058, 10617839.362961083650589 ], [ 2695178.255351334810257, 10617843.194646343588829 ] ] ] ] } },
```

I'm aware that these are in different locations -- I edited the coordinates of the map so that they display the area covered by the new GeoJSON.

When the map displays with my GeoJSON nothing shows up.  But when I use the original GeoJSON (and move the window back to that area), it overlays polygons onto the OSM map.

Does anyone know why this might be?  Is there a hyper-specific GeoJSON format needed for Leaflet?

Answer (score 2):

Your coordinates are completely off (e.g [ 2695178.255351334810257, 10617843.194646343588829]).

First value (i.e. longitude) should be 0 to 360

Second value (i.e. latitude) should be -90 to 90

Comment: Wow. You are very correct.  I converted .shp to .geojson in QGIS.  I guess I had some setting set incorrectly.

Comment: Are the numbers I have from using the wrong map projection on the original .shp file?

Comment: I think so. Apparently shapefiles have a whole different way to encode coordinates (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shapefile). Is this helpful for you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25498644/importing-geojson-into-leaflet-with-coordiantes-n-crs-epsg3857?rq=1

Comment: I was eventually able to convert the original shapefile in QGIS to WGS84 EPSG 4326.  No other projection worked.  Not sure why.